# Cannot remove my user from Site Administrators

Tags: permissions

I would like to remove my user from the Site Admistrators just for test purposes.
I've removed it in Site Administrators in Central Administration and all groups I was in.
I am not even in the server or domain admistrators.
Still, my user is administrator.

What could I do?

Comment: Are you the only site collection admin for the site that you are trying to remove yourself from? If yes i would say that it must be a fail safe function.

Comment: You can always to do it from the sitecollection root directly. Just add this to your url. /_layouts/15/mngsiteadmin.aspx

Comment: Have you checked the site collection administrators from site settings?

Comment: user19952 there is another admin,, so I am safe in that respect. Now there is only une site collection administrator and it's not my user. Nevertheless, I still can do all administrative operations.

Answer (score 0):

You could first try to do it from the rootsite. > *site settings > site collection administrators* and remove your user from there.

Or add this to your site collection url: */_layouts/15/mngsiteadmin.aspx*

But i'm pretty sure that you always need at least one owner.

Or you could try to set another admin with powershell and in that way you are not the site collection administrator anymore.

```
Set-SPSite -Identity "<SiteCollection>" -OwnerAlias "<User>"
```